# Grid with viewport height and inner scrolling div

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a layout that uses a grid that takes up the entire browser viewport (`height: 100vh`) and then allows a div within one of the grid items to scroll in the Y dimension.

Here's some example code. There are three grid areas: a header across the top, a left nav, and a content area in the lower right.

I'm trying to make it so div inside the content area (the `big-list`), is the only thing with a vertical scrollbar, and the rest of the UI stays on the screen.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.outer-grid {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 180px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
}
.top-bar {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 200,200);
}
.header {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 8px;
}
.left-nav {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 8px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
#content {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
#search {
    width:100%;
}
.big-list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.big-list div {
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(230,230,230);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer-grid">

    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
    </div>

    <div class="left-nav">
      <div>Nav 1</div>
      <div>Nav 2</div>
      <div>Nav 3</div>        
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <input id='search' type="text"/>

      <div class='big-list'>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Last Row </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you able to use a fixed height on `grid-template-rows` or `#content`?

Comment: No, I want that second row of the grid to expand to fill the viewport.

Answer (score 9):

### Solution

Add this to your code:

```
#content {
  display: flex;          /* new */
  flex-direction: column; /* new */
}

.big-list {
  flex: 1 0 1px;          /* new */
}
```

```css
.outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 180px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
}

.top-bar {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 8px;
}

.left-nav {
  /* overflow-y: scroll; */ /* removed */
  padding: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#content {
  display: flex;            /* new */
  flex-direction: column;   /* new */
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
}

.big-list {
  flex: 1 0 1px;             /* new */
  overflow-y: auto;          /* adjusted */
}

.big-list div {
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-nav">
    <div>Nav 1</div>
    <div>Nav 2</div>
    <div>Nav 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <input id='search' type="text" />
    <div class='big-list'>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Row ... </div>
      <div> Last Row </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Explanation

For an overflow to occur, content must overflow the container.

For content to overflow the container, the container must have a size limitation. Usually it's a fixed or maximum length, such as `width: 150px` or `max-height: 50vh`.

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):*

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container
>   must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

You're trying to render a vertical scrollbar on your list element (`.big-list`), but it doesn't have a height limitation.

The heights you have in place for it are:

1. `1fr` (for the row, set by `.outer-container`). This isn't even a length. It's a distribution of free space. This cannot trigger an overflow.
2. `height: auto`, which is the default height on elements. This doesn't provide any limitation, as content will simply keep expanding the container. So this cannot trigger an overflow, either.

Since you don't want to use fixed heights, but want the list element to render a scrollbar when necessary, you've got to be a bit sneaky. Still, it's a win-win. The browser gets what it wants. You get what you want.

Add this to your code:

```
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.big-list {
  height: 1px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

So what you're doing is turning the list element's parent (`#content`) into a flex container for the sole purpose of enabling `flex-grow` on the child (`.big-list`).

You set a tiny fixed height on the list element (`height: 1px`). This satisfies the condition needed for an overflow. The browser gets what it wants.

Then, for the list element to fill remaining height, you add `flex-grow: 1`. You get what you want.

Since `height` is equivalent to `flex-basis` in a column-direction flex container, you can simplify to:

```
flex: 1 0 1px /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
```

Comment: Thanks! You said "neither that element or any of its ancestors have a height limitation". But `.outer-grid` has `height:100vh`. Isn't that a height limitation?

Comment: Yes. You're right. But that won't trigger the overflow on `.big-list`. For overflow purposes, it applies only to `.outer-grid`. I revised my answer with a correction.

Comment: The MDN docs mention that `height` or `max-height` on an element allow `overflow` to have an effect. How did you know that `flex-basis` also does this? Is that mentioned somewhere?

Comment: Yes. It's in the flexbox spec. `flex-basis` is the equivalent of `height` / `width` in a flex container.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my night! ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can apply height  to `.big-list` and `.left-nav` to `height: calc(100vh - 51px); overflow-y: auto;` of subtract height of `header` and `search`

```
.big-list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:calc(100vh - 56px);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.outer-grid {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 180px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
}
.top-bar {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 200,200);
}
.header {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 8px;
}
.left-nav {
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 8px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    height: calc(100vh - 51px);
}
#content {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
#search {
    width:100%;
}
.big-list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:calc(100vh - 56px);
}
.big-list div {
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(230,230,230);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer-grid">

    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
    </div>

    <div class="left-nav">
      <div>Nav 1</div>
      <div>Nav 2</div>
      <div>Nav 3</div>        
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <input id='search' type="text"/>

      <div class='big-list'>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>    
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Row ... </div>
 <div> Last Row </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```